# Add quotes around some words, but only when copy pasting - opposite of the q tag

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do somewhat of the opposite of the `<q>` tag. The q tag visually displays quotes in the web page, but if you copy paste the text, the quotes are not present in the pasted text. I want the opposite - no visual quotes in the web page, but quotes are present in the copy pasted text.

Why? Because I sometimes prefer to use other visual styles in my webpage instead of quotes. But when a user copies the text, since I cannot rely on them pasting the text into something capable of preserving the rich formatting/styles, I wish to revert to using quotes because they're simple ascii characters which will work in any plain text context.

I'll give a concrete example to help clarify.

Given:

```css
.qq { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
I am <span class=qq>some quoted</span> text.
```

When the user views the page, they should see:
[image: example of browser visual rendering of the html]

But if they were to copy the text and then paste it somewhere, the pasted text would be:

```plaintext
I am "some quoted" text.
```

Is it possible via just css? I'd prefer not to use js.

I don't really care what the html/css needs to be, so if quotes, or the q tag etc... need to be present in the html source instead of a span, that's totally ok.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of without JS is to put the quotes in the markup and hide them using CSS. The markup will get a bit messy though. Something like:

```css
.lq,
.rq {
  font-size: 0;
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
I am <i class="lq">“</i>some quoted<i class="rq">”</i> text.
```

Comment: I chose this answer because IMO it struck a good balance of simplicity, support/reliability, maintainability, and it seemed to worked well in practice. 

An issue I didn't anticipate but encountered with some other answers is that some of them didn't always result in either "just A" or "just B" behavior. They worked correctly when pasting into a plaintext context/notepad, but when pasting into a context that supports rich formatting (such as ms word), you ended up with both quotes and yellow background, which isn't ideal.

Comment: I'm glad to have provided a solution that fits your requirements - or at least some of them. From my experience, most things are possible in some way or another, but if you get too creative or too complex you will at some point end up with unexpected behavior. I did  get curious to explore @Bario's font-face suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

using JS you can do this way

```
        window.addEventListener("copy", (e) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            const selection = document.getSelection();

            let selectedText = selection.toString();
            let selectedTextWithQuotes = `"${selectedText}"`;

            // FOR SAVING IN CLIPBOARD
            event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", selectedTextWithQuotes);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only css you could use transparent double quotes:

```css
.qq { background-color: yellow; }

quote {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0px;
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
I am <quote>"</quote><span class=qq>some quoted</span><quote>"</quote> text.
```

### UPDATE

**A not recommended alternative**. [It is compatible with 75% of browsers.](https://caniuse.com/?search=%40font-face%20size-adjust) (I'm referring to the `@ font-face: size-adjust` property), but it's an alternative.

For the main font you create a character set that includes only the double quote, but with the `size-adjust` property at `0%`. The remaining text will be rendered with the secondary font.

```js
I am "some quoted" text.
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'myFont';
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/crimsonpro/v23/q5uUsoa5M_tv7IihmnkabC5XiXCAlXGks1WZzm1MP5s-.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0022;
  size-adjust: 0%;
}

.yourBody {
  font-family: myFont, 'courier new';
}

.qq { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<div class="yourBody">
  I am "<span class=qq>some quoted</span>" text.
</div>
```

Comment: `<quote>` isn't a valid html tag.

Comment: @SuperStormer I'm not so sure you're right, but that's not the point, I used a custom element just to make the `html` clearer and more readable, it could also be pseudo code for the purpose of the answer. Cheers.

Comment: @SuperStormer Just to clarify (although, I repeat, that was not the point) `<quote> </quote>` is [still valid for 96% of browsers](https://caniuse.com/custom-elementsv1). [Custom Elements on whatwg.org](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements).

Comment: Although custom elements are a valid part of HTML5, `<quote>` isn't a valid custom element name. I agree it does make the markup more readable, and it would probably work well in most modern browsers, but it doesn't conform to any current specification.

Comment: Using a custom font / char range was a very interesting strategy. It also allows targeting certain characters without needing to add markup around them. It didn't work great for this use case because I ended up with both quotes and yellow background when pasting into word, but I will play around with this idea in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.quote-character-left {
    margin-right: -0.5em;
    opacity: 0;
}

.quote-character-right {
    margin-left: -0.5em;
    opacity: 0;
}

.quote-text {
    display: inline;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p>I am <span class="quote-character-left">&quot;</span><span class="quote-text">some quoted</span><span class="quote-character-right">&quot;</span> text.</p>
```